# Theres a SQL sub-topic in JOINS i dont understand and would like to get help, which is the difference between ON (and AND!) and WHERE

Tags: python, sql

Theres a SQL sub-topic i dont understand and would like to get help,which is up there in this QUESTION TITLE. Is there someone who can give me a specified detailed explanation? there's a subtle difference but i cantt quite FEEL IT you know ; )

```
SELECT p.name AS product_name, p.price, producer.name AS company_name
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN sales_history s
ON s.product_id = p.id
AND s.date BETWEEN '2015-02-01' AND '2015-02-05'
LEFT JOIN producer
ON p.producer_id = producer.id
WHERE s.amount IS NULL;
```

thanks in advance, and have a lovely day

Comment: It's hard to give a specific and detailed explanation without a similar detailed question but I'll try: ON specified which records you want to join. Depending on the type of join, you'll get a specific set of results. The WHERE clause filters that result for a given creiteria. AND is just to chain multiple criteria, working for both, ON and WHERE.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.